# Cannot join mp3 file and avi file with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using this code to join an mp3 file and video file with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i /file1.mp3 -ab 128k -i /file2.avi  -vcodec copy -f avi /file3.avi
```

But this code gives that error

```
Option ab (audio bitrate (please use -b:a)) cannot be applied to input file /file1.mp3 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file /file1.mp3.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
```

How can i do this job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Add an audio stream

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -shortest out.avi
```

- This example will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) instead of doing any encoding.
- `-map 0` will map all streams, including any audio and subtitle streams, from input "`0`" (`input.avi`) to the output.
- `-map 1:a` will map all audio streams from input "`1`" (`audio.mp3`) to the output. `ffmpeg` treats album art as a video stream, so this option will only map the audio.
- `-shortest` will make the output duration the same as the shortest input duration.

## Replace an audio stream

If you want to replace the audio in `input.avi` with `audio.mp3` one method is to explicitly choose your desired streams:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest out.avi
```

## Re-encode

Sometimes you may want to change the audio format or lower the bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i audio.flac -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -shortest out.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
     ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -acodec copy -i file.avi -vcodec copy -f avi file2.avi

Comment: but i need to change mp3 bitrate to 128k ??

Comment: In that case use -acodec mp3 -ab 128k (I think that is the magic incantation, I am not at my computer right now to verify -- on my phone)

Comment: it says "[NULL @ 0x3a895c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy'
copy: Invalid argument"

Comment: What is in your input files codec-wise?  Also, what is the exact command line giving the error?  Ffmpeg is notorious for being tricky to set up, but works fairly well once you have it right.